# Cisco client VPN connects but no ping or VPN access after hibernate/sleep

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I'm using Cisco Client VPN.  When my laptop (Windows 7 Enterprise) sleeps or hibernates I can still connect (or least the client tells me the VPN connection was successful).  However, I cannot ping or connect to VPN'd resources.  I have tried killing virus protection (McAfee), but that didn't help.

Does anybody have any insight and a solution to this problem?

Comment: My Answer below is probably more relevant to latest windows 10 of 2021+
** Disable Power Saving mode** on the ethernet adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no real true "fix" for this problem. It's documented as an issue as Cisco defect ID CSCsf96588.  A check of Cisco's [release notes (page 5)](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/cisco_vpn_client/vpn_client5006/release/notes/vpnclient5006.pdf) for VPN client 5.0.06 and .07 both mention it as an issue.

They've issued a software fix to change the way the client re-establishes a secure tunnel, but it's still a problem for platforms.

Cisco's workaround is a recommendation to shut down the VPN client before going into sleep/hibernation mode.

Answer (score 2):

A way to resolve this issue is to turn off VPN connection via Task Manager before the system goes to hibernate. Find below the scripts that I use to turn off and disconnect VPN before hibernation and then to turn it on after the computer comes back up from sleep.

Before Hibernate:

```
    REM Before Hibernate
    REM Begin the Task: On an event
    REM Setting Basic
    REM Log:  System
    REM Source: Kernel-Power
    REM Event ID: 42
    REM The system is entering sleep.


    "c:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN Client"\vpnclient.exe disconnect
    taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq vpngui.exe"
```

After Hibernate:

```
    REM After Hibernate

    REM Begin the Task: On an event
    REM Setting Basic
    REM Log:  System
    REM Source: Power-Troubleshooter
    REM Event ID: 1
    REM The system has resumed from sleep.

    cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN Client"
    start vpngui.exe
```

reference: [How to execute a script on sleep, hibernate, resume, and shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/321151/how-to-execute-a-script-on-sleep-hibernate-resume-and-shutdown)

**UPDATE1:** Another way that I was able to resolve it is to disconnect from current WiFi and connect to a another one. It also fixed problem few times.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco Anyconnect has this behaviour when the computer sleeps the and then come back the VPN connect and all internet is lost.
and requires a simple reconnect which of course is painful especially with 2FA.

SO...
** Disable Power Saving mode** on the ethernet adapter

Go into ethernet adapter setting a disable the power/energy saving mode. it has been renamed once before.
navigate to the adapter and then into "Configure" where you should find a advanced tab with a ton of different switches.

** Disable Power Saving mode** This will literally stop the hardware adapter from switching off during a nap.
It has nothing to do with anyconnect. it is the hardware.

this will most likely solve various VPN issues, because this is not VPN related.

well maybe the VPN cause the connection to stay down once down, because the moment you disconnect the VPN, internet returns.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting network-manager worked for me:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```