# How to make a window task run everytime I enter my password/unlock the computer?

Tags: windows, tasks

How to make a window task run every time I enter my password/unlock the computer?

System is windows 7.

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: windows 7. i've up the IP

Comment: Use the Task Manager and selct the task to happen on the event that handles when a user logs into the account.  Here is one such tutorial http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/67503-task-create-run-program-startup-log.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a script on sleep, hibernate, resume, and shutdown](http://superuser.com/questions/321151/how-to-execute-a-script-on-sleep-hibernate-resume-and-shutdown). chunkyb2002's answer tells you about the different Task Scheduler triggers available.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set triggers for tasks, as opposed to running on a schedule.

- Start Task Scheduler from the start Menu
- Select the Task Scheduler Library in the left nav pane
- Select Action > Create Task... (not Create Basic Task...) from the menu bar
- In the new Create Task window, select the Triggers tab
- Click on the New... button
- In the "Begin the task:" drop down, select "At log on" or "On workstation unlock"
- Repeat and create a second trigger for the task that covers the one you didn't select before
- configure the rest of the task normally

Comment: This also works for Windows 10