# UltraUxThemePatcher not working, possible issue with UxStyle that wasn't uninstalled before Creators Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, themes

I updated to Creators Update (V1703 Build 15063.540) and I want to use custom themes. So I patch my files using the latest UltraUxThemePatcher. However, after patching, whenever I try to open the "Themes" setting, it crashes. If I uninstall it, I can open "Themes" again. I've tried selecting the custom theme first, and then installing UltraUxThemePatcher but the themes don't work so clearly there is something wrong there.

I don't know if there is some conflict with UxStyle which was what I was using to patch for custom themes before the Creators Update. I can't uninstall UxStyle using the uninstall option from "Programs and Features". When I try, Compatibility Assistant says:

*This app can't run on this PC. UxStyle doesn't work on this version of Windows. An updated app may be available*

I've run sfc /scannow, I don't know if that removes UxStyle.

Any help?

Edit: The "duplicate" does not solve my problem. I am trying to use UltraUxThemePatcher, not UxStyle. UxStyle does not work with the Creators Update. https://github.com/riverar/uxstyle/issues/37

Comment: Tried all those

1) Tried using "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth", themes still don't work.
2) Tried replacing my aerolite.msstyles and 3 dlls that normally get patched for themeing with clean ones from VM, themes still don't work.
3) Tried using UltraUxThemePatcher on VM (Same Windows Build), themes work there. So patcher is not the issue.

Comment: The error you are getting points exactly to the issue, and the issue is the same as the duplicate. It appears UltraUxThemePatcher is a port of UxStyle, and the Compatibility Assistance has identified this issue. If UxStyle won't work, it is very likely that UltraUxThemePatcher will not work for the same reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10- UxStyle patch not working properly](https://superuser.com/questions/1103253/windows-10-uxstyle-patch-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. As I suspected, it was due to UxStyle not being uninstalled and conflicting with UltraUxThemePatcher. The uninstall option for UxStyle still does not work for me, even after I tried disabling Compatibility Assistant. However, you can effectively disable UxStyle by removing the executable "unsignedthemes.exe" that is located in the "Windows" folder. AFAIK, UxStyle runs that exe at startup and that is how it allows themes.

Answer (score 0):

You can successfully run the windows uninstaller for UxStyle by using the "Compatibility Administrator" (downloadable from the Microsoft ADK). Select "UxStyle" from the list of blocked programs and "disable" to make it startable. This way the uninstaller will be unblocked and run.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07XZrn6ZxUM

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/dn913721.aspx#adkwin10