# How to mount vhd in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, vhd

How do you mount a .vhd file in Windows Vista? In Windows 7 you use disk management but there is no option available for Windows Vista.

Comment: You can't without third party software mount vhd is a Windows 7 feature

Answer (score 2):

- Download [MS Virtual Server 2005 R2 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2994)
- Download [its update](https://web.archive.org/web/20120721044146/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24896)
- Open an administrator command prompt and run `setup /v"PATCH=%cd%\KB948515.msp ADDLOCAL=VHDMount"`
- Choose custom install
- (optional) Use/add the [following](http://forums.hexus.net/software/122575-windows-mounting-vhd-files-without-virtual-machine.html) reg file for a very handy mounting

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Virtual.Machine.HD]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Virtual.Machine.HD\shell]
  @="Mount" 

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Virtual.Machine.HD\shell\Dismount - Commit]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Virtual.Machine.HD\shell\Dismount - Commit\command]
  @="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Virtual Server\\Vhdmount\\vhdmount.exe\" /u /c \"%1\""

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Virtual.Machine.HD\shell\Dismount - Discard]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Virtual.Machine.HD\shell\Dismount - Discard\command]
  @="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Virtual Server\\Vhdmount\\vhdmount.exe\" /u /d \"%1\""

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Virtual.Machine.HD\shell\Mount]

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Virtual.Machine.HD\shell\Mount\command]
  @="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Virtual Server\\Vhdmount\\vhdmount.exe\" /m \"%1\""

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vhd]
  @="Virtual.Machine.HD"
  ```
- (optional) Install [Virtual PC 2007](https://web.archive.org/web/20120729020516/https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=24439) for a nice GUI to create/manage/merge disks

---

If you are using Home editions (officially unsupported by Virtual Server) my recommended workaround is using a hex editor on its setup.exe to change `CAP_DisallowedOS = 1` string to 0.

---

In some rare(?) occasions, msiexec may crash almost at the end of installation with a 0xc000000d BEX error (VHD Mount Merge Module Custom Dll [does](https://web.archive.org/web/20090307012918/http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2005/03/07/388739.aspx) [something](https://web.archive.org/web/20170712185529/http://win2kgaming.prophpbb.com/topic715.html) fishy while trying to install Microsoft Virtual Server Storage Bus driver)

Mysteriously, stopping WPDBusEnum service seemed to fix the issue.

---

Addendum: I have been getting quite a lot of BSOD with standby. So I decided for unmounting the thing before going to sleep, and re-mounting after resume. Unfortunately `vhdstor` driver seems to get stuck after awhile, locking disk file against further actions.

I eventually came down to [program](https://superuser.com/a/1272661/567466) `Microsoft Virtual Server Storage Bus` on/off for every suspension

Comment: Great work!! Do you think it's possible to patch W8.1 editions in order to use VHD tools (for powershell) as well, using a similar method? Also, what does the `CAP_DisallowedOS` do? (Google returned 0.)

Comment: It's a property set by the VSWIXCustomActions dll when, guess what, it happens not to like your OS. I suppose you could even fake somehow the reported version then, but at the end of the day I just found easier to edit that bit in the installer. As for newer Windows, the problem seems more to do with a "hardblock" entry in the [compatibility](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/installing-virtual-server-2005-r2-sp1-on-windows-7) database than the msi. But as I already commented below, I don't really see much a point when from 7 onward VHD is natively supported OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DiskPart & scripts](http://www.howtogeek.com/51174/mount-and-unmount-a-vhd-file-in-windows-explorer-via-a-right-click/), or use [Virtual Server 2005 R2](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/3595/windows-xpvista-how-to-attach-a-vhd-file/)... or how about [Gizmo Drive](http://arainia.com/software/gizmo/overview.php?nID=4)?

Comment: Diskpart supports VHDs [only](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/7/2009/10/07/diskpart-exe-and-managing-virtual-hard-disks-vhds-in-windows-7/) starting from W7