# Asus laptop - wireless turns off when on battery, even though power settings say "maximum performance"

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop

I find myself turning on wireless in the mobility screen ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MJH6.png)) almost every day. The [power settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic6zF.png) shows maximum performance for wireless.

Any ideas? Thanks

EDIT:

1. In the adapter properties/power management it is *not* configured to be turned off to save power.
2. I remembered that it mostly happens AFTER sleep mode, like if it sleeps for a long time and I wake it up - it's almost guaranteed I'd need to turn "wireless" on

Comment: Please run command prompt as Administrator, enter `powercfg -energy` and post the result file. For more info see [Use PowerCfg in Windows 7 to Evaluate Power Efficiency](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/).

Comment: @harrymc - http://pastebin.com/JUB3MYZd (raw html) or http://pastebin.com/d6eV3DY1 (text paste)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your bios setting yet ? some laptop can set to turn off wireless on sleep in the Bios.

or you can make the following a bat file:
netsh interface set interface "Wireless Network Connection" Enable

then put that in window scheduler, run on workstation unlock.
then the wifi would turn on everytime you unlock your laptop screensaver.

Comment: yep, looked at all BIOS screens, couldn't find anything related to power or wireless

Comment: the scheduler idea is a good one, I'll try to see if I can do it on wakeup instead of on login (I often want to remote control into the computer, so login is a bit too late). [this](http://superuser.com/questions/84442/trigger-task-scheduler-in-windows-7-when-computer-wakes-up-from-sleep-hibernate) suggests it's possible

Comment: so, does it works ?

Comment: automation saves lives ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the `powercfg -energy` report I find two suspicious entries :

```
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend

Power Policy:802.11 Radio Power Policy is Maximum Performance (Plugged In)
The current power policy for 802.11-compatible wireless network adapters is not configured to use low-power modes.
```

You might consider disconnecting all unneeded USB devices after reviewing their power options, as well as setting the wireless on battery to some power-saving mode,
but I don't believe that this alone will fix the problem.

I don't know if the above warnings are connected to the problem, but my advice is:

1. Update all drivers and firmware (including BIOS) from the [G74Sx download page](https://www.asus.com/ROG/G74SX/#support_Download_30).
2. Run Windows Update, Search for updates, and patch everything including optional updates. Reboot and repeat until no more updates are found.
3. If the problem remains, run Microsoft's [USB troubleshooter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Tips-for-solving-problems-with-USB-devices) from Internet Explorer
4. If nothing works, do [Repair Install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html) to
   fix Windows and preserve user accounts, data, programs, and system drivers.
5. I advice against the obvious next step - reinstalling Windows.
   In the worse case, one can create a batch script for turning on the wireless so as to make
   it easier on you.

Comment: great answer, yes, bios is probably a little outdated but most of the other stuff should be pretty recent, I'll try to update anyway. I'm wondering about what you said about USB, all I have connected is the mouse and I don't see how it can be related to the wireless adapter

Comment: I don't think it's the mouse not sleeping, but rather the usb hub controller. This is probably normal if the usb mouse needs to wake-up the computer.

Comment: Question: Is the wireless marked as allowed to wake up the computer?

Comment: where is that setting again? do you mean the wake-on-lan? is it only in the bios or is there a windows setting?

Comment: Yes, I meant setting both Wake on Lan options in Device Manager / Network adapter / Properties / Power Management. Sometimes it is also in the BIOS at the Power management section or maybe called "Power On By PCI Devices" or somewhere else depending on the version.

Comment: Well, it seems like I have the latest drivers for everything (incl. BIOS), I do not want to reinstall right now. I couldn't find ANY wireless or power settings in the BIOS. Anything more I can try?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

copy this link into your windows explorer "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections"

Right click your wireless card. Go to Properties. Click the configure button
choose power management tab. Uncheck "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power."

Comment: it was unchecked: [image](http://i.imgur.com/E76xDJ1.png)

Answer (score 0):

you might have a manufacturer's software installed that does some power management. Check to see if there is by going to Services or Add/Remove Programs and finding any of them that might be running in the background with names with prefixes of the manufacturer. If so, remove the bloatware.