# What's the easiest way to schedule a windows XP task to run when going into or coming out of standby?

Tags: windows-xp, sleep, scheduled-tasks

This is an issue with Windows XP (SP3)

I have some software on my machine my employer requires me to run.  However, if this software is running when my machine wakes up from standby, it consumes 100% of my system's CPU and all other tasks run 10x to 20x slower than normal before the offending task finally does whatever it's doing.  In short, my machine is unusable for about 2 minutes after it comes out of standby.

If I remember to quit the task before putting my machine in standby, things are fine, and running it fresh after waking up takes only a second or two.  But I'd like to automate the process.

Is there a way of running a script which is triggered by standby state changes?

Comment: Its been discussed at length with this question: http://superuser.com/questions/84442/trigger-task-scheduler-in-windows-7-when-computer-wakes-up-from-sleep-hibernate?rq=1

Comment: As far as I can tell, attaching a task to an event in Event Viewer is a feature that does not exist in Windows XP

Comment: It would seem based on that fact what you want is not possible on `Windows XP`.  I will flag this question to unmarked as a duplicate.  In the future it helps to mention the operating system in the question itself and not just use a tag to identify it.

Comment: The OS is mentioned in the title/question.  I should have also repeated it in the detailed questoin

Comment: I would flag this question for moderator review and request it be unmarked as a duplicate.  I attempted to do that but the failed to simply request that happen.