# Keeping Virtual Wifi (Soft) Access point after reboot

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, virtual-wifi

I create a Virtual Wifi (soft) access point using following command on cmdline with Admin Rights:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=<SSID> key=<Password> keyUsage=persistent
```

and then Start this Access point using:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Thing is for this, I need Admin Rights, and I have to do same process after every reboot.
Is there any way where I can keep this AP even after reboot?

I can add this in a BAT File and run on Every start up, but I have a machine which I don't have admin rights. I can ask the guy with Admin Rights once a while but I don't want to bug him!

Update: This AP gets disabled even after Sleep or Hibernate!

Comment: Have you checked this out on serverfault?: http://serverfault.com/questions/436345/netsh-wlan-start-hostednetwork-command-at-start-up-with-ws2012

Comment: @gnp Interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nag your administrator once only, to get him to set up your batch file
to start automatically after boot with administrator permissions.

This is done by scheduling the execution of the batch file.
For complete instructions, see this article :

[Make Vista launch UAC restricted programs at startup with Task Scheduler](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/make-vista-launch-uac-restricted-programs-at-startup-with-task-scheduler/616)

Once this is set up, you may in the future modify the batch file and the new version
will execute on the next boot.

Comment: You can also schedule for after Sleep or Hibernate with the "At Workstation Unlock" trigger. See also this post: [Trigger Task Scheduler in Windows 7 when computer wakes up from sleep/hibernate](http://superuser.com/questions/84442/trigger-task-scheduler-in-windows-7-when-computer-wakes-up-from-sleep-hibernate).