# batch script to "scan for hardware" in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, batch, powershell

There is this [issue with Wifi](http://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/2fkhij/for_those_with_wifi_issues_fixworkaround/) on the Surface Pro 3 that can be easily fixed with a script that does the equivalent of running "Scan for hardware changes" in the Device Manager. This script will be executed automatically whenever the computer comes back from sleep.

How would one go about doing this? Powershell?

Comment: You could probably do this with `devcon`. Or perhaps something from [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction.aspx).

Comment: [Scan for hardware changes in Windows using command line](http://serverfault.com/questions/547130/scan-for-hardware-changes-in-windows-using-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

First to run an event on wakeup, use task scheduler to register a task for that event (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/84442/trigger-task-scheduler-in-windows-7-when-computer-wakes-up-from-sleep-hibernate) for more details).

For the second, use the [devcon utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) mentioned by @Bob.

All that remains is to point the task that you created at the batch file.