# How to run a program on log on of any user in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler, wake-up

**Note**: Read, before you vote for duplicate question!

I need to execute a program on every log on. By that I used these energy settings to test the behaviour:
[image]

And I force the log on screen on wakeup, too:
[image]

Now I created a new task and created a trigger for `At log on of any user`, but it never fires. It fires only if I restart my machine completely or it wakes up from hibernation but not if only the monitors are switched on again.

I did some research and some people suggest to use the [event id 42 or 1 as trigger](https://superuser.com/a/84453/129262), but this does not work for Windows 10.

Is there a separate event for "log on after monitor wake up"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger Task Scheduler in Windows 7 when computer wakes up from sleep/hibernate](http://superuser.com/questions/84442/trigger-task-scheduler-in-windows-7-when-computer-wakes-up-from-sleep-hibernate)

Comment: @Bungicasse No its not. You should read the question first.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an easier way (feel free to answer), but this is how I solved it by myself:

1.) [Open the Group Policy Editor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731745(v=ws.11).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396) by running gpedit.msc in the windows search.

2.) Navigate to Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> [Advanced Audit Policy Configuration](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/03/11/getting-the-effective-audit-policy-in-windows-7-and-2008-r2/) -> System Audit Policies - Local Group Policy -> Logon/Logoff and activate the monitoring for `Audit Logon` and `Success`
[image]

3.) Now create your task and set a trigger for the protocol `Security`, the source `Microsoft Windows security auditing.` and the [event 4624](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn319080(v=ws.11).aspx)
[image]

Finished!