# Trigger Task Scheduler in Windows 10 when display wakes up

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, event-viewer, wake-up

I don't have enough rep to comment on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/84442/trigger-task-scheduler-in-windows-7-when-computer-wakes-up-from-sleep-hibernate) post so I am posting my own question that is very similar to that post.

I have an app I want to run when the computer goes idle, and then quit when I wake it back up. The problem I'm having is that I set my screen to turn off, but my computer doesn't actually go to sleep. This is both to keep Folding@Home going while I am not at my desk and to make the wake up process quicker.

I've used the Task Scheduler to trigger on idle, but I can't find any event anywhere that is logged when the display turns off. I literally (not figuratively) went through all of Event Viewer. I've also tried to use the "Stop if computer ceases to be idle", however that doesn't actually quit the program it opened.

Thoughts?