# Rebinding Keys on a Dell Keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-registry, keymap

I have a Dell Multimedia Keyboard, similar to this one:

[image: keyboard image]

It has many non-standard keys, like the small circular ones across the top, and the "Multimedia" keys above INSERT/HOME/PAGE_UP.

They can be rebound through simple registry entries. Some sample ones are included below:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\15]
"ShellExecute"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe http://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\16]
"Association"=".cda"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\17]
"ShellExecute"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\SnippingTool.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\18]
"ShellExecute"="calc.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\7]
"Association"="http"
```

I've rebound the "MAIL" key to, instead of booting Outlook, to booting Firefox directed at my G-Mail account. I've rebound the button that would normally open "MY COMPUTER" to instead boot the Windows 7 "Snipping Tool", something I find very useful.

Now, I'm looking to do some other things that I don't already know how to do. Note that answering this question doesn't necessarily require any knowledge about the keyboard or rebinding the keys: I can add, for any given key, a "ShellExecute" entry, and it will simply execute the following command as if it was typed at a Command Prompt. (I'm aware I dumbed that down rather significantly, but bear with me. I'm not really a Windows guy myself.)

I use the volume knob for it's intended purpose, to change volume. I would like to change, however, a different key, to "reset" the Windows volume level back to exactly 50%, or, as it refers to it, "50", on it's 0-100 scale.

I'm looking for the "program" (what I would type at a command prompt? these are still just Sys32 programs in the PATH, aren't they?) that, I imagine, would take arguments, to change Sound/Volume settings under Windows 7. Perhaps, for clarification, something that might take the form "C:> SetVolume -slevel 50" or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're going to need some additional software to do this for you.  There's some excellent links [here](https://superuser.com/questions/82229/how-to-control-master-volume-in-windows-7) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/42039/change-windows-xp-sound-volume-via-the-command-line).

In particular:

[NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) is an application that changes the volume and more.

Example of use:

```
* Increase the system volume by 2000 units (out of 65535)
nircmd.exe changesysvolume 2000

* Decrease the system volume by 5000 units (out of 65535)
nircmd.exe changesysvolume -5000

* Set the volume to the highest value
nircmd.exe setsysvolume 65535
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for. Despite involving third-party software (I was hoping for a native Windows solution), sometimes nativity is overrated. The program is small, concise, does everything I could need it to, nothing I don't, and doesn't consume system resources when I don't need it. Thank you.

Comment: NirCmd is awesome. OT, but a cool example: "at 21:00 nircmd standby" and you've got a Standby schedualed for 9:00 tonight.

Answer (score 5):

You can perform "key rebinding" on Windows for any keyboard using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).  Here are some examples (from my AutoHotKey startup configuration) that show how to control the sound card:

```
 #z::Send,{VOLUME_MUTE}
 #=::SoundSet,+5
 #-::SoundEet,-5
 Capslock::Send,{MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE}
```

('#' means the Windows Key, you can also specify any combination of control, shift, and alt keys).

Comment: AutoHotKey is great for rebinding normal keyboard key combinations, but does it also support rebinding extra keys/buttons/knobs that a keyboard like the OP's has?

Comment: Yes: if you bring up the AutoHotKey window and switch to the Key History view, you can view a list of all the recently pressed keys, with the names or codes that can be used inside AHK.

Comment: +1 Actually I found names for them listed in the AutoHotKey Help file in a section about Multimedia and Internet keyboards -- such as `Volume_Mute`, `Launch_Mail`, `Browser_Home`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another third party option for fine volume control, [volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html) (also from Nirsoft)

[image]

Comment: While I think volumemouse is very useful utility for what it does and use it myself, I don't believe there's any way to configure it to reset the volume level back to exactly 50% -- nor in general rebind the OP's Multimedia keys. You can use it to mute/unmute the volume with certain key + scroll-wheel combinations, however.