# How can I access volume levels from the command line on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, audio, script, cygwin

### What I need

I'm looking for a tool or a script that allows me to access the Windows volume levels from the command line. Ideally it would allow me to get and set all volumes including application levels, but I'd settle for only getting, and only the master level. I don't mind if it uses `PowerShell`, `WMI`, `JavaScript`, `.Net`, Voodoo, or butterflies. Any solution that will just give me a number that I can further process to fit a range from 0% to 100% will do.

Put another way, the prompt parts are the black box that I need filled:

```
C:\> getvol master
50
```

or even

```
C:\> wmic <alias> where "device='master' and name='volume'" get name,value
Name    Value
Volume  0xDEADBEEF
```

I don't mind if I have to spend some time to wrap it or even write something myself if the tools to do so are freely available. In the latter case, I'd need some pointers/proof-of-concept for the core, but I can manage the cruft on my own. Also I'd like to avoid installing new development frameworks just for this purpose (note that both [music2myear's](https://superuser.com/a/394965/112553) and [iglvzx's](https://superuser.com/a/395496/112553) answers were given *before* I introduced these requirements).

As "platforms", I have available:

- anything that comes with Windows 7 Home Premium
- anything that comes with Cygwin
- Perl
- Python
- Ruby

Generally, open-source solutions are greatly preferred. Closed-source tools are ok as long as they're freeware and the source can be trusted. Commercial solutions are no-go.

### What I don't need

- There are a few [similar](https://superuser.com/questions/82229/how-to-control-master-volume-in-windows-7) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/374306/my-keyboard-has-no-volume-control-keys-how-do-i-assign-shortcuts-to-control-the) that mostly deal with setting the volume. Most of all, I need to *get* the volume, not set.
- There is [`nircmdc`](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html), which supports setting volume, but not getting.
- There is a key[1] in my registry that has values that change predictably when I adjust the volume via the GUI mixer, but I'd guess reading from that key is prone to breakage on hardware changes or system upgrades. Unless I can rely on the solution being reasonably future-proof, I can't use it.
- There are `AutoHotKey` and `WSH` solutions for setting the volume on the Web, but a) they too are only good for setting and, worse, b) they use `SendKeys` or automated mouse movement to control the GUI. Automating the GUI is not an option.

The `##windows` channel on freenode is unhelpful as ever, Google overflows with hacks and half-baked workarounds, and I can't tell a WinAPI call from a Wiccan incantation.

Does anyone know of a way?

---

1. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4D36E96C-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000\MixerSettings\eLineOutTopo\PrimaryNode000`

Comment: Semms like [WMI is not an option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801595/retrieve-current-mixer-levels-with-wmi) :(

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/284527/where-are-the-vista-win7-volume-mixer-settings-stored

Comment: Do you need me to expand my answer? I wasn't sure of you needed more, since you seem to have experience with programming. I can provide an example on how you can use AutoHotkey to easily achieve your goal.

Comment: I think it's a very good suggestion, thanks again, but AHK bit me once and I'm shy ever since. I probably wouldn't use it even if it was a fully fledged-out solution. Nothing keeping you from expanding on it for future readers/more upvotes though. :)

Comment: (as a note that reg. doesn't even seem to exist on my box, so...it may be unstable indeed).  See also my c++ answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21056089/32453

Answer (score 5):

This question was asked and answered on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640106/how-to-get-current-volume-of-system-sound-device-in-windows-7

The answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4640225/704977

> You're looking for the EndpointVolume API. This is part of the new
>   audio APIs that were released in Windows Vista, and it can be used to
>   get or set the master volume.
>   ...
>   There's a complete managed wrapper library available on CodeProject: Vista Core Audio API Master Volume Control.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Will I have to code this myself or do you maybe know of a little tool that sprang from the question/answer? I haven't touched C# before: if I have to code it myself, is there a compiler freely available?

Comment: At worst you'll need to download Visual Studio C# Express, which is free: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express

Comment: I only found this particular answer while searching for a solution to your question. I have not pursued further research to see if there's a compiled binary already publicly available.

Comment: This google search appears to have some promise: https://www.google.com/search?q=get+current+volume+by+command+line+windows

Comment: Great, thanks in any case. This will be my fallback if no one knows of a tool. Much obliged!

Comment: That one appears to be C# oriented.  If you're looking for a C++'ish option, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21056089/32453

Answer (score 4):

I know you said you did not want an AutoHotkey solution, but I believe the [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) API has what you are looking for:

- **[SoundGet](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundGet.htm)**
- **[SoundGetWaveVolume](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundGetWaveVolume.htm)**
- Related: [SoundSet](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm), [SoundSetWaveVolume](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSetWaveVolume.htm), [SoundPlay](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundPlay.htm)

You do not need to create GUIs or use hotkeys with AutoHotkey. You can write powerful command line utilities by compiling an `.ahk` script. That being said, you will want to look at the [FileAppend](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileAppend.htm) command for working with `stdout`.

Comment: here's one that does it: gist.github.com/rdp/8363141 (though a straight console app for it may be simpler/easier, see other comments here)

Answer (score 1):

You can get Windows volume via Windows Core Audio API

```
pEndpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(&currentVolume);
```

I've wrote a C++ program for it, you can use it directly from the command line as [adjust-volume.exe](https://github.com/WingTillDie/adjust-volume/releases/download/v2.0.0/adjust-volume.exe):

Usage:

```
# Get current sound volume
./adjust-volume.exe
# Output: Current sound volume: 0.1

# Set current sound volume to 0.2
./adjust-volume.exe .2
```

Repo:
https://github.com/WingTillDie/adjust-volume

Comment: Hi, identical answer, so on the borderline spam.  Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://superuser.com/help/promotion)

Answer (score 0):

The master volume is stored in the registry location:

```
...\#eSpeakerTopo\Properties\{7fb7b48f-531d-44a2-bcb3-5ad5a134b3dc}
```

For example, this REG file sets the master volume to 100%.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses\{6994ad04-93ef-11d0-a3cc-00a0c9223196}\##?#HDAUDIO#FUNC_01&VEN_8384&DEV_7680&SUBSYS_83847680&REV_1034#4&31e60982&0&0001#{6994ad04-93ef-11d0-a3cc-00a0c9223196}\#eSpeakerTopo\Properties\{7fb7b48f-531d-44a2-bcb3-5ad5a134b3dc}\20000]
@=hex(ffff1003):00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00
```

The key name may differ. You need to restart for changes to take effect.

You may not be able to edit or open the `Properties` or `{7fb7b48f-531d-44a2-bcb3-5ad5a134b3dc}` key in `regedit`. Although you have the necessary access permissions, you may receive an error like this:

```
[Window Title]
Error Opening Key

[Content]
{7fb7b48f-531d-44a2-bcb3-5ad5a134b3dc} cannot be opened.
An error is preventing this key from being opened.

[OK]
```

This is because the key name is too long. You will have to temporarily rename the long key name to one character and then rename it back.