# How to get master audio volume value of windows with cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, audio

I want to to get the **master volume value** of my windows pc with the command prompt. I prefer to have an **one-line** solution.

I've searched on many places for the solutions, but they all don't work.

*I want to use this for Windows Power Automate (to set as variable), so if someone knows an other solution, you're welcome!*

Comment: It would be better if you actually told us what you'd tried that didn't work rather than just saying 'so many'… as we don't know which you've tried.

Comment: Stackoverflow, Superuser and Google.

Comment: That doesn't really tell us anything. Also, add pertinent information to your question, don't use comments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get audio volume from command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/934220/get-audio-volume-from-command-prompt)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio This doesn't work for me unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by master volume value. if you want to adjust volume on your computer automatically download nircmd and run this command nircmd.exe changesysvolume [Number for example 1000 or -1000] this modifies your volume. if you want more info on this topic use this website https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html at the bottom of that page is were you can find the download link for nircmd then open the nircmd.exe file as an administrator then click add to directory.