# Turn on/off volume from batch file or command Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, volume-mixer, command-line-tool

I had a piece of code for windows 8.1 that turned the volume off/on so could put it in a batch file for startup. Need something for windows 10 if it's available

Comment: This may have been answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355891/change-audio-level-from-powershell

Comment: Found the code called nircmd.exe still works fine on 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control master volume in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/82229/how-to-control-master-volume-in-windows-7)