# Mute Windows 10 while screen is locked

Tags: windows-10, audio, login, lock-screen

When I take the laptop out of its bag and open it, I'd prefer if it didn't suddenly start playing a song or the sound of a movie, before I've successfully logged in. While it would be nice if the source of the sound (VLC/YouTube/etc) paused, the far more important part is that I don't want to hear the sound.

If no general solution is available, I'd be happy with one that works with Youtube + Chrome.

I tried [Mute On Lock](http://www.superutils.com/products/mute-on-lock/) and one other software for Windows 7, neither of them worked in Windows 10.

Comment: One more thing I just found, I confirmed both of these work with Windows 10. . .  https://superuser.com/questions/82229/how-to-control-master-volume-in-windows-7/1255277#1255277 If you are looking for something a bit more Windows native, then this may be the way to go rather than AutoIT—just trying to help you here so let me know your thoughts when you get a chance. You'd just create VBS scripts and execute with Task Scheduler from a batch or whatever, etc. with applicable triggers still. Sorry for all the comments but I'll come back around and remove at some point.

Comment: I have posted an answer to a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/a/1336693/230978)

Comment: Interesting, yesterday, out of a sudden, my laptop started muting all sounds while on lockscreen and I hate it. I want to disable this and keep playing my music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Windows 10 Auto Mute Volume

Consider using the free [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) application and with a simple [Send()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) function using [Send Key list](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm) `{VOLUME_MUTE}` or `{Volume_down}` sending keyboard shortcuts to adjust the volume.

You can use [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) and setup [triggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841(v=ws.11).aspx) to execute the as needed e.g. `At logon`, `On workstation unlock`, `On an event` and on specific event ids, etc.

[image]

> ### AutoIT Example A Logic
>
> *This appears to toggle from unmute to mute or vice versa when executed*
>
> ```
> send ("{Volume_Mute}")
> exit
> ```
>
> ### AutoIT Example B Logic
>
> *This will toggle down the volume 100 times*
>
> ```
> #include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
> Local $i = 0
> Do
>    send ("{Volume_down}")
>    $i = $i + 1 ; Or $i += 1 can be used as well.
> Until $i = 100 ; Increase the value of $i until it equals the value of 10.
> Exit
> ```
>
> <sub>[source
>   ideas](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/146238-mute-sound-on-windows-boot-up-via-script-or-command-line-urgent/)</sub>

### Further Resources

- [Triggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841(v=ws.11).aspx)
- [Do...Until](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/Do.htm)

Comment: @Peter - Furthermore, see https://superuser.com/questions/84442/trigger-task-scheduler-in-windows-7-when-computer-wakes-up-from-sleep-hibernate for some tips on event ids to see for triggering an action with Task Scheduler. I look forward to hearing whether or not you were able to work with this solution.

Comment: Hi, quite old question, but this is just half working for me: I'm trying to mute on lock and unmute on unlock, and although the `Task Scheduler` logs the action was successfully launched and even logs a return code of `0` in both cases, the only action working is the one launched on unlocking, no matter if volume was muted or not. I'm thinking it can be because computer is locked, so `send` has no effect?

Comment: So yes, it's because the computer is locked, so it accepts no keystroke input. I found I can do it with `SoundSet, +1, , mute`.

Answer (score 0):

A more up-to-date answer could be:

Use the open source application, WinMute:
https://github.com/lx-s/WinMute